# Using "Content-Encoding":"GZIP"

Tags: http, http-headers

I want to send large amount of json over http to sever.

If I use "Content-Encoding":"GZIP" in my httpClient, does it automatically convert the request body to compressed format?

Answer (score 3):

No, the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.2.2) describes content encoding.  If you are sending `Content-Encoding` you need to make sure that the content **is** in that encoding.

If you send `Content-Encoding: gzip` and the message in plain text you will (quite rightly) receive an `HTTP 400`.  The body of a `gzip` message will always start with `0x1f 0x8b` and if the server does not find that int he POST request it is right to complain.

Another reason for this is that you need an appropriate `Content-Length` header.  This will not be the length of the original JSON, it must be the length (in bytes) of the gzipped JSON.

You need to perform the `gzip` of the JSON before sending anything since you need to know what to place in `Content-Length` beforehand.

Extra note: If the JSON is that huge (e.g. several gigabytes) you probably will need `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, which comes with its own complications.  (You do not send `Content-Length` but add the length of the chuck to the body itself.)

Comment: a) RFC 2295 is totally irrelevant; see RFC 7231 instead. b) I have no idea why you think T-E is relevant here...

Comment: @JulianReschke - a) You're right, updated.  b) T-E is allowed in a POST (as far as I am aware), it is an option for OP in case his JSON is huge (not strictly needed for the answer, but may be useful).

Comment: When the compressed content reaches server with a header  "Content-Encoding":"GZIP", does the server automatically decompress it?

Comment: @user902997 - Yes and no.  The server must read the entire message, check `Content-Encoding` and then decompress the message.  On the other hand: Apache, Cherokee, Nginx, (and likely almost all others) will do the transparently and give an already decompressed payload to the actual application (say PHP or Rails).

Answer (score 2):

If it automatically does this, is 100% dependent on which http client you are using and if they implemented it that way. Usually setting a header will *not* automatically encode it, at least in the clients I regularly use.